# Joining windows xp users on windows 2008 domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

I was wondering is it posible to join windows xp clients on an windows 2008 domain.
If yes what are the benefites or negative sides of this.

The problem is that i have about 100  users. 80 of them have windows xp and about 20 have windows 7. I dont know should i install domain on windows 2003 r2 or windows 2008.

Sory for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP will work just fine with Windows 2008, with no real problems or special considerations.

The only thing I would say is that both are old operating systems now, XP in particular, and I'd suggest that time and money invested in expanding a network based on either system right now instead of upgrading to something more modern is a bad investment, but there's no technical issue here.

The same argument applies to creating a Windows 2003 domain and joining Windows 7 clients to it - It'll work just fine, but Windows 2003 is a poor investment of time at this point for the same reason XP is.

Comment: Aha, ok. 1 more question, from the windows 7 side, if i make 2003 domain can i join windows 7 systems and what are the negative side of that.

Comment: I modified my answer to talk about Windows 2003 DCs @superduper - essentially the same issue as Windows XP with regards to being a poor use of time imho, but no technical issues.